# Jackson Serialization One to Many Relationships

Tags: java, spring, jackson

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "departments")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Employees> employeesList; 

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
@JsonBackReference
private Departments departments;
```

I have two Entities, Employees and Departments. Each Employee belongs to a Department.
I used the @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference to avoid infinite recursion.

But I cannot get Department of Employee from the Employee side as it gets ignored.
In Laravel I could establish bidirectional relationships to get two way data.

**What is the best way to implement and get bidirectional data when using Jackson for Spring? I want to know which department an employee is in from the employee side.**

Comment: you can delete all the annotation above the Departments attribut , because when you call the list employees that will retrive also the departemnents for each employees

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could you please explain a bit more?You mean i should remove the Many to One annotations? If i remove Annotations above department, will it be a bidirectional relationship?

Comment: no, will it be a unidirectional relationship but if you need to see the department from teh employees list this is the solution , in the second solution to have a bidirectional i will post a solution for you

Comment: Do you have a method removing/adding elements from/into `employeesList`? (Actually it should be `employees`) Without this method, it always fails. All the project code is needed to check what is wrong; specially I want to know what you mean by "ignored".

Comment: Yes, @Charfi, making it unidirectional helped. First I reversed them but faced problems saying cannot manage reference. Then I Removed Jackson Annotation from Departments. Now the Unidirectional Works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's annotate the relationship with @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference (
reverse them in your exemple) to allow Jackson to better handle the relation:

```
public class Employees{
     @ManyToOne
     @JsonManagedReference
     private Departments departments;
}
public class Departments {
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "departments")
     @JsonBackReference
     private List<Employees> employeesList; 
}
```

this solution can help you , if not yet you can use the annotation **@JsonIdentityInfo**
that help with the serialization of entities with bidirectional relationship:

We add the class level annotation to our “Employees” entity:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "id")
public class Employees{ ... }
```

And to the “Departments ” entity:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "id")
public class Departments { ... }
```

Comment: Thank You. I removed Jackson annotation from Departments. Unidirectional works fine. Do you mean i should use JsonManagedReference on both Employees and Departments? Also if i use JsonIdentityinfo should i remove @Entity from my class?

Comment: sorry I make a mistake in my response but I fix it, you should use **JsonBackReference** above the list attribute.
For the **JsonIdentityInfo** keep the **Entity** and add the annotation, this annotation that will help with the serialization of entities with bidirectional relationship

Comment: Thanks. If i use JsonManagedReference on Department departments, i get error saying cannot manage when i try to save in database. After i removed Json Annotation on department, it works fine.Now only JsonBackReference on list attribute.

Comment: if i use unidirectional relationship, and i want to know how many employees are in a department, what is the best way to get the query. Also should i remove "@OneToMany" from list attribute and keep "@ManyToOne" on departments attribute?

Comment: if you want to use the unidirectional relationship you shoud remove the one of those annotation and keep the annotation in the principal class in your application,and you can get the counts of the employees or departements with a query (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)